# Polygons still being displayed after updated state

Tags: reactjs, react-google-maps, react-google-maps-api

I am trying to conditionally render some polygons from data contained within `result`. I want for whenever the value of `result` to change, new polygons to be displayed on the map. Currently, the map displays the new polygons but the previous polygons remain visible on the map as well. Code below, using @react-google-maps/api 2.2.1 .

```
import React from "react";
import "./MapAnalysis.css";
import {GoogleMap, useJsApiLoader, Polygon, Marker } from '@react-google-maps/api';

function MapAnalysis({ result }){
  return (
    <div className="mapContainer">
      <MyMap
     result={result}
    />
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapAnalysis;

function MyMap({ result }) {

  const containerStyle = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  };
  
  const center = {
    lat: 40.7608,
    lng: -102.8910
  };

  const { isLoaded } = useJsApiLoader({
    id: 'google-map-script',
    googleMapsApiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_API_KEY
  })

  return isLoaded ? (
    <GoogleMap
    mapContainerStyle={containerStyle}
    center={result ? {
      lat: result.observer_details.latitude,
      lng: result.observer_details.longitude
    }
    : center}
    zoom={result ? 15: 4}
    streetViewControl={false}
    mapTypeId = 'satellite'
    options = {{
      streetViewControl: false
    }}
  >
     {result !== null ?
        <> 
        {result.squares.map((item) => (
          <Polygon
          paths={item.square_coords}
          options={{
              strokeOpacity: 0,
              strokeWeight: 0,
              fillColor: `rgb(${item.color[0]}, ${item.color[1]}, ${0})`,
              fillOpacity: 0.25,
              visible: true,
          }}
          />
    ))}
        <Marker
          position={{
            lat: result.observer_details.latitude,
            lng: result.observer_details.longitude
          }}>
        </Marker>
        </>
        : <></>}
    </GoogleMap>
  ) : <></>
}
React.memo(MyMap)
```

I added a marker and it does update position and the previous one is removed on an update to `result`.

[Here is the first run with the polygons and the marker displayed:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kInCn.png)

[Then after an update to result, the original polygons are still visible but the marker has moved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLU1Z.png)